# two parallel calls either one succeeds in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I want something like the `async` library to do two parallel calls either one succeeds in javascript and then the callback to operate on the succeeded output. It does not seem that `async` has that. `parallel` would err out if either one fails.

In general, if I have `N` tasks, and I want to guarantee `m` succeed and use the output from these `m` calls, how can I do it?

Comment: Strictly speaking, Javascript is not parallel, it has only one thread and can only execute one thing at a time.If you want multi threading use webWorkers as each one will have its own thread..Async in Javascript refers to non blocking IO calls. For handling deferred tasks use promises .

Answer (score 1):

#### `Promise.race`

You want `Promise.race` (assuming you are willing to move from `async` to promises):

```
Promise.race([d1, d2]) . then(result =>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

> The `Promise.race` method returns a promise that resolves or rejects as soon as one of the promises in the iterable resolves or rejects, with the value or reason from that promise.

#### Writing `race` in callback fashion

As far as I can see `async` does not provide the equivalent of race, but you can do something like:

```
async.race = function(tasks, callback) {
  var done = false;
  tasks.forEach(function(task) {
    task(function(err, data) {
      if (done) return;            // another task finished first
      done = true;
      callback(err, data);
    });
  });
};
```

Perhaps you want a variant of `race` where errors are ignored--although that design seems questionable. In that case:

```
async.firstFulfilled = function(tasks, callback) {
  var done = false;
  tasks.forEach(function(task) {
    task(function(err, data) {
      if (err || done) return;    // skip failures
      done = true;
      callback(err, data);
    });
  });
};
```

Return first *n* non-error cases:

```
async.firstNFulfilled = function(n, tasks, callback) {
  var result = [];
  tasks.forEach(function(task) {
    task(function(err, data) {
      if (err) return;
      result.push(data);
      if (!--n) callback(null, result);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: but is this in still asynchronous? seems `forEach` yes, but just to confirm.

Comment: also, the `err` case shouldn't set `done=true`, right?

Comment: The definition of `race` is that a failure also "wins" the race.

Comment: could you provide an answer where only success "wins" the race please?

Comment: Or even my generalized question above?

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery.Deferred and jQuery.when to achieve this (there are other promise libraries too).

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();

$.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {
   // this will execute only when both deferred objects are resolved
   // and the values passed to those for resolving will be available 
   // through v1 and v2
});

$.get('url1').success(function() { d1.resolve('value for v1') });
$.get('url2').success(function() { d2.resolve('value for v2') });
```

jQuery.when: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

jQuery.Deferred: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: But that's not what he wants. He wants to wait for either one to resolve, then move ahead with that result without waiting for the other one. Also, may be a matter of opinion, but of all the libraries to use in your example, jQuery is probably the least preferable, not just because it's broken, but also because for all we know the OP is working in node (actually, he most likely **is** working in node, since he refers to the `async` library).