# Is there a built-in function to configure a race in q?

Tags: javascript, q

Is there a built-in function to configure a race in the `q` JavaScript library?

Example:

```
function fnThatReturnsAPromise1() { /*...*/ }
function fnThatReturnsAPromise2() { /*...*/ }

//Pseudocode: I want to have the first one of these functions that resolves, be the result
q.race([fnThatReturnsAPromise1,fnThatReturnsAPromise2])
.then(function(resultOfWinner) {
  // ...
});
```

Edit: there appears to be a race method in the source, but it is not mentioned in the documentation. https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L738

Comment: What do you mean by "configure"???

Comment: @Bergi I have updated my question with an example.

Comment: Downvoters, please explain, so that I can improve my question.

Comment: @Kay, it is a race between two asynchronous functions. It is similar to a deliberate race condition. Can you explain how that is not a race?

Comment: @Kay Why is this not a race? It looks exactly like a race to me (in the sense of `Promise.race`). Here is a related question, although not Q-specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643593/two-parallel-calls-either-one-succeeds-in-javascript/32644193#32644193.

Comment: @BenAston I didn't downvote, but I'd guess they are downvoting this because you could simply check the documentation to answer your question. https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference

Comment: @forgivenson I have checked the documentation and could find no mention of it. I also then checked the source code and found a `race` method, hence the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain that in your question then. Mention you are asking about the `race` method you found in the source code (and include the code for it perhaps)

Comment: Well, the documentation does not show anything that looks like a race, so it does not seem unreasonable ask if there's something he missed, since Q has so many other bells and whistles it's a little bit odd it doesn't have this one, which after all is even in the native Promise spec. Basic principle of dealing with down-voters is to ignore them. If they wanted to explain, they would already have done so in a comment.

Comment: @BenAston I just looked at the source, and it does look like there is a `race` function, so why don't you just try using it and see if it is available?

Comment: It seems that code works as is, did you try it? Seems odd that it's not documented though.

Comment: I am using q 0.9.7 and I get an error with the code above to do with the presence of `answerPs`.

Comment: That code (if it worked) does not do exactly what you say you want. That code will fulfill **OR** reject the promise when any of the inputs fulfill or reject. If you want something which fulfills on the first fulfilled promise (and presumably ignored rejections?), you'll need to write it yourself anyway. However, I cannot see why the code should not work in the sense of doing what it intends to (which is the same as `Promise.race`). Are you sure you're passing it an array?

Comment: @torazaburo OK thanks for the clarification. Actually the rejection behavior you describe is OK in my use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [v0.9.7](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/CHANGES.md#097) there is a `Q.race` method that does exactly what you want. It's [still not documented yet](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/issues/403) in the [API reference](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) though.

Also, since [v1.0.1](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/CHANGES.md#101) the function is available as `.race` on the ES6-compliant [`Q.Promise`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/commit/ac8ea2601ba28ca4cea4518dc58bd2ff8f56d135) object.